# Getting:ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when upload App with streamlit Cloud

Tags: python, github, pytorch, operating-system, streamlit

When I upload my code on GitHub using Streamlit. And I face some problem. Here are the part of log and `requirements.txt`:
Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to False.
2023-02-24 14:13:19.778 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 564, in _run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)
File "/app/cug-drug-side-effects-prediction/App.py", line 19, in 
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdkit/Chem/Draw/**init**.py", line 21, in 
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import rdMolDraw2D
ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
torch==1.13.0
matplotlib==3.5.2
translate==3.6.1
numpy==1.21.6
pandas==1.3.5
streamlit==1.15.1
plotly==5.11.0
scipy==1.7.3
networkx==2.6.3
rdkit==2022.9.2
requests==2.28.1
Pillow==9.4.0
scikit_learn==1.2.1
torch_geometric==2.1.0.post1
-f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cu116.html
torch-sparse
-f https://data.pyg.org/whl/to
```

In addition, I use Windows. And this code could run on pycharm.

I searched a lot of blog and most of them did not make any difference. And it seems that in most case, this problem occurs on Linux.

Comment: Can you share the link to the deployed app?

Answer (score 0):

Was just working through the same problem. I was able to resolve the issue by creating a packages.txt file and adding libxrender1 to the new text file. The packages.txt file manages linux dependencies as shown in the link below.
https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/app-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, you can resolve it by
add in packages.txt
libxrender1
patchelf

From https://pypi.org/project/rdkit-pypi/ , it says to install patchelf as dependencies when installing in linux environment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).